# Rails 6 Active Storage Attachment 404 not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activestorage

I'm encountering a very strange issue in my Rails 6 application with Active Storage.

You can add a PDF file to a feedback, which is stored via Active Storage - in development this works without problems, you can save and open it.

It kind of works in production aswell, but the problem appears when I re-deploy the application with Capistrano. Before the deploy, all files saved up to this point are shown without problems. After the re-deploy, the files stored BEFORE are not found anymore - without any changes on the database.

That's my view code (I tried with `url_for`, `rails_blob_path` and `service_url` via controller aswell)

That's what my log says before the re-deploy (successfully shows the file):

```
Started GET "/rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDRG9JYTJWNVNTSWhNREZuWjJNek9HeDZNV1ZvT0RWaFkyZDFkVGQ2YW04NU5XdzBkQVk2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpWkdsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SWxkbFlrMWxiblZsSUZCeWIzTmxiblJoZEdsdmJpNXdaR1lpT3lCbWFXeGxibUZ0WlNvOVZWUkdMVGduSjFkbFlrMWxiblZsSlRJd1VISWxRek1sUWpWelpXNTBZWFJwYjI0dWNHUm1CanNHVkRvUlkyOXVkR1Z1ZEY5MGVYQmxTU0lVWVhCd2JHbGpZWFJwYjI0dmNHUm1CanNHVkE9PSIsImV4cCI6IjIwMjAtMDctMTRUMTg6MDg6MjIuOTQ5WiIsInB1ciI6ImJsb2Jfa2V5In19--0a52cfc77ce14105dc290ff569d50b637231f613/WebMenue%20Pr%C3%B5sentation.pdf?content_type=application%2Fpdf&disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D%22WebMenue+Prosentation.pdf%22%3B+filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27WebMenue%2520Pr%25C3%25B5sentation.pdf" for 172.16.118.100 at 2020-07-14 20:03:48 +0200

Processing by ActiveStorage::DiskController#show as PDF

Parameters: {"content_type"=>"application/pdf", "disposition"=>"inline; filename=\"WebMenue Prosentation.pdf\"; filename*=UTF-8''WebMenue%20Pr%C3%B5sentation.pdf", "encoded_key"=>"eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDRG9JYTJWNVNTSWhNREZuWjJNek9HeDZNV1ZvT0RWaFkyZDFkVGQ2YW04NU5XdzBkQVk2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpWkdsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SWxkbFlrMWxiblZsSUZCeWIzTmxiblJoZEdsdmJpNXdaR1lpT3lCbWFXeGxibUZ0WlNvOVZWUkdMVGduSjFkbFlrMWxiblZsSlRJd1VISWxRek1sUWpWelpXNTBZWFJwYjI0dWNHUm1CanNHVkRvUlkyOXVkR1Z1ZEY5MGVYQmxTU0lVWVhCd2JHbGpZWFJwYjI0dmNHUm1CanNHVkE9PSIsImV4cCI6IjIwMjAtMDctMTRUMTg6MDg6MjIuOTQ5WiIsInB1ciI6ImJsb2Jfa2V5In19--0a52cfc77ce14105dc290ff569d50b637231f613", "filename"=>"WebMenue Prõsentation"}

Completed 304 Not Modified in 1ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 370)
```

Then, after redeploy I get this 404 not found error on the exact same file:

```
Started GET "/rails/active_storage/disk/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDRG9JYTJWNVNTSWhNREZuWjJNek9HeDZNV1ZvT0RWaFkyZDFkVGQ2YW04NU5XdzBkQVk2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpWkdsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SWxkbFlrMWxiblZsSUZCeWIzTmxiblJoZEdsdmJpNXdaR1lpT3lCbWFXeGxibUZ0WlNvOVZWUkdMVGduSjFkbFlrMWxiblZsSlRJd1VISWxRek1sUWpWelpXNTBZWFJwYjI0dWNHUm1CanNHVkRvUlkyOXVkR1Z1ZEY5MGVYQmxTU0lVWVhCd2JHbGpZWFJwYjI0dmNHUm1CanNHVkE9PSIsImV4cCI6IjIwMjAtMDctMTRUMTg6MTI6MzQuNTE3WiIsInB1ciI6ImJsb2Jfa2V5In19--9d281265e57a7c0d3cd53af1f8e1a6e098605d3c/WebMenue%20Pr%C3%B5sentation.pdf?content_type=application%2Fpdf&disposition=inline%3B+filename%3D%22WebMenue+Prosentation.pdf%22%3B+filename%2A%3DUTF-8%27%27WebMenue%2520Pr%25C3%25B5sentation.pdf" for 172.16.118.100 at 2020-07-14 20:07:34 +0200

Processing by ActiveStorage::DiskController#show as PDF

Parameters: {"content_type"=>"application/pdf", "disposition"=>"inline; filename=\"WebMenue Prosentation.pdf\"; filename*=UTF-8''WebMenue%20Pr%C3%B5sentation.pdf", "encoded_key"=>"eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaDdDRG9JYTJWNVNTSWhNREZuWjJNek9HeDZNV1ZvT0RWaFkyZDFkVGQ2YW04NU5XdzBkQVk2QmtWVU9oQmthWE53YjNOcGRHbHZia2tpWkdsdWJHbHVaVHNnWm1sc1pXNWhiV1U5SWxkbFlrMWxiblZsSUZCeWIzTmxiblJoZEdsdmJpNXdaR1lpT3lCbWFXeGxibUZ0WlNvOVZWUkdMVGduSjFkbFlrMWxiblZsSlRJd1VISWxRek1sUWpWelpXNTBZWFJwYjI0dWNHUm1CanNHVkRvUlkyOXVkR1Z1ZEY5MGVYQmxTU0lVWVhCd2JHbGpZWFJwYjI0dmNHUm1CanNHVkE9PSIsImV4cCI6IjIwMjAtMDctMTRUMTg6MTI6MzQuNTE3WiIsInB1ciI6ImJsb2Jfa2V5In19--9d281265e57a7c0d3cd53af1f8e1a6e098605d3c", "filename"=>"WebMenue PrÃµsentation"}

Completed 404 Not Found in 2ms (ActiveRecord: 0.0ms | Allocations: 799)
```

Any idea what is happening here? Maybe a problem with NGINX file caching or something?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay after digging into some research I found out why this happened - I'll try to explain it in case someone may be getting into similar issues when deploying with Capistrano.

So, it's not directly a Rails or Active Storage related issue. I'm using local storage for my attachments, so I do not store them on Amazon or Google or Azure - the default storage location for those attachments is the 'storage' folder in the root of the application - so I checked `storage.yml`:

```
local:
  service: Disk
  root: <%= Rails.root.join("storage") %>
```

And in my `production.rb`:

```
  # Store uploaded files on the local file system (see config/storage.yml for options).
  config.active_storage.service = :local
```

My problem was the following: This folder itself is **not** added to `.gitignore` by default, just the contents **inside** the folder are ignored by GIT.
So it happened that I pushed an empty storage folder to my repo every time I do a `git push`. This will of course **override** the storage folder which was used before in production on every deploy with Capistrano.

What solved the problem in my case was to add the storage folder to the `linked_dirs` array, which you can specify inside the `deploy.rb`:

```
append :linked_dirs, 'log', 'storage', 'tmp/pids', 'tmp/cache', 'tmp/sockets', 'vendor/bundle', '.bundle', 'public/system', 'public/uploads', 'node_modules'
```

With this option set, the folder will not be overwritten on every deploy, instead it will be shared between the releases and the previously uploaded files will stay accessible.

I hope this will help somebody in the future, if you ask yourself why your files are disappearing :').